# Yii2 Framework: Call to undefined function app\controllers\VisitorForm

Tags: php, yii2

I am working in Yii2 Framework. In my model, I have class

```
class VisitorForm extends Model
{
    public $station;
    public $center;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['station', 'center'], 'required'],
            ];
    }
}
```

and in my SiteController class I have the action method

```
 public function actionVisitor()
    {

        $model = VisitorForm();
        if($model->load(yii::$app->request->get())){
            return $this->render('visitor', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
```

Also, I have included `use app\models\VisitorForm;`.
Also in my view directory I have `visitor.php`.

The above code is exactly similar to the `EntryForm` code give in Yii2 Definitive Guide.

But I am getting the error while executing the code at line

```
$model = VistorForm(); // throwing error at this line


Call to undefined function app\controllers\VisitorForm()
```

I am not able to figure out, what is going wrong with me.
at the line, where I create the model

Comment: Are you on advance yii2 ?

Comment: Are you using yii2 basic or advanced ?

Answer (score 0):

I realised my mistake.
It should be

```
$model = new VistorForm();
```

instead of

```
$model = VistorForm();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have add this line on SiteController.php Cause you are going to use VistorForm class inside the SiteController

```
use app\models\VisitorForm;
```